# Sql syntax error about ``

Tags: php, mysql

I have never seen this problem. I want to make a MySQL query (insert, update, select) but MySQL gives an error.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM option
```

and error:

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option' at line 1]

but if i put ``

```
SELECT * FROM `option`
```

it's working. What can i do?

Comment: Did you forget the semicolon?

Comment: Reserved Word?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: yes you right, its reserved words. thank you so much

Comment: A better idea: don't use reserved words as table/column identifiers

Comment: @saidOnder Don't forget to accept an answer too =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`option` is [reserved word for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you need to enclose it with backticks or avoid it by changing table name

```
SELECT * FROM `option`
```

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is a reserved keyword in MySQL (SQL).

So, after using backtick (`), it is not considered as keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backtick for option, Since it is a reverse word. 
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `option`;
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Comment: it's reserved not `reverse`

Comment: @plainjane: It's "it's", not "its".

Answer (score 0):

option is a keyword
check it here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html
use backtick for option
**select * from 'option'**